# Ordering data in a list view

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I try to retrieve data from Firebase Database on a `ListView` but the data is not showing the newest in the top rathen than the first thing exists in database.

[this is from firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCvFw.png)

[this is a screenshot from the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plemG.jpg)

I would like the app to show the most recent text in the top of the list. This the code i use,

```
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myArray);

        mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        mListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        mListView.animate();
        mRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            String value=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            myArray.add( "- "+ value);
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace this line - 
`myArray.add( "- "+ value);`  with this line - `myArray.add(0,  "- "+ value);`. This will make your items to be added to the top position of your arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `myArray` is a `List` and not an actual array as the name implies. That being said a quick solution is to *reverse the order* of that list. You can use `Collections.reverse()` for that.

```
@Override
public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
 String value=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
 int index = Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.getKey());
 myArray.add(index,"- "+ value);
 // Reverse the order of that list
 Collections.reverse(myArray);
 myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Have you realized that you are reversing the mArray everytime a new child is added to the list from firebase?

Comment: Of course, that's why I added a *quick* solution. I've never said the right one. From what it seems the fellow wants just to test how firebase database works.

Answer (score 0):

try adding android:stackFromBottom="false" to ListView in Xml file